# Add another different column based on previous column

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Let's say i have a table like this in database

```
Name  Day  VALUE1  VALUE2
========================
A     mon      1       2
A     fri      2       2
```

and i want it like

```
Name  VALUE1(mon)  VALUE2(mon)  VALUE1(fri)  VALUE2(fri)
=====================================================
A        1             2            2            2
```

can i make something like this? if i can, pls tell me how to make this with query

Comment: Would you always only expect Monday and Friday?

Comment: yes only for monday and friday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a pivot query:

```sql
SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DAY = 'mon' THEN VALUE1 END) AS "Value1(mon)",
    MAX(CASE WHEN DAY = 'mon' THEN VALUE2 END) AS "Value2(mon)",
    MAX(CASE WHEN DAY = 'fri' THEN VALUE1 END) AS "Value1(fri)",
    MAX(CASE WHEN DAY = 'fri' THEN VALUE2 END) AS "Value2(fri)"
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do self full outer join as follows:

```
Select coalesce(m.day,f.day) as day,
       M.value1 as monval1,
       M.value2 as monval2,
       F.value1 as frival1,
       F.value2 as frival2
  From your_table m full outer join your_table f
    On m.name = f.name 
   And m.day = 'mon' and f.day = 'fri'
```